# Is there a way in JOOQ to pull a number of records without multiple DB calls?

Tags: crud, jooq

In our webapp we have a number of places where you would be updating a number of tables in one complex form/view.  In raw SQL I would probably select a bunch of columns from a bunch of tables and edit that one record on the primary table as well as related parent/child tables.

In hibernate I would probably just pull a JPA entity for the main table and let hibernate fetch the parent/child relationships as I populate the view. And then later pull from my view back to the entity and call entitymanger .perist/merge.

In JOOQ I have a number of options but it appears you can pull a main record via selectFrom/fetch then use fetchChild fetchParent to pull typed related records like so...

```
    LoadsRecord load = dslContext.selectFrom(LOADS)
            .where(LOADS.ID.eq(id))
            .fetchOne();
    SafetyInspectionsRecord safetyInspection = load.fetchParent(Keys.LOADS__FK_SAFETY_INSPECTION);
```

So this way I am able to pull related records in a typesafe manner.  The only annoying thing is I have to run another full query every time I call fetchParent or fetchDhild.  Is there a way to eagerly fetch these all at once to avoid multiple round trips to the DB?

It is really nice to have these classes like LoadsRecord for CRUD screens, it makes updating the DB easy.

Comment: It almost looks like I could use this technique of implicit joins with type safe nested tables to achieve this but it is only working in 3.17 which isnt out yet https://blog.jooq.org/projecting-type-safe-nested-tablerecords-with-jooq-3-17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Classic approach using joins

There are various ways you can achieve materialising a to-one relationship. The simplest one being a simple `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` if the relationship is optional.

E.g.:

```java
Result<?> result =
ctx.select()
   .from(LOADS)
   .join(SAFETY_INSPECTIONS)
   .on(LOADS.SAFETY_INSPECTIONS_ID.eq(SAFETY_INSPECTIONS.ID))
   .fetch();
```

You probably want to work with the generated records thereafter, so you can use various mapping tools to map the generic `Record` types to the two `UpdatableRecord` types for further CRUD:

```java
for (Record r : result) {
    LoadsRecord loads = r.into(LOADS);
    SafetyInspectionsRecord si = r.into(SAFETY_INSPECTIONS);
}
```

#### Using nested records

Starting from jOOQ 3.15 and [#11812](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11812), [`MULTISET`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/) and [`ROW`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/nested-records/) operators can be used to create nested collections and records. So, in your query, you could write:

```java
Result<?> result =
ctx.select(
      row(LOADS.ID, ...), 
      row(SAFETY_INSPECTIONS.ID, ...))
   .from(LOADS)
   .join(SAFETY_INSPECTIONS)
   .on(LOADS.SAFETY_INSPECTIONS_ID.eq(SAFETY_INSPECTIONS.ID))
   .fetch();
```

That would already help map the nested data structures into the desired format. Starting from jOOQ 3.17 and [#4727](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4727), you can even use table expressions directly to generate nested records:

```java
Result<Record2<LoadsRecord, SafetyInspectionsRecord>> result =
ctx.select(LOADS, SAFETY_INSPECTIONS)
   .from(LOADS)
   .join(SAFETY_INSPECTIONS)
   .on(LOADS.SAFETY_INSPECTIONS_ID.eq(SAFETY_INSPECTIONS.ID))
   .fetch();
```

This new feature is definitely going to close one of jOOQ's biggest gaps. You could even simplify the above using [implicit joins](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/) to this:

```java
Result<Record2<LoadsRecord, SafetyInspectionsRecord>> result =
ctx.select(LOADS, LOADS.safetyInspections())
   .from(LOADS)
   .fetch();
```